# Will 11.10 come with keyboard short-cuts for the file and applications lenses?

Tags: unity, 11.10, shortcuts

Since alpha/beta of 11.10 I miss my very often used shortcuts <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> will they be implemented again in the final version of 11.10?

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> are still the default keyboard shortcuts for the Application and File lenses.

If they're not working for you while you were using the Alpha/Beta then they could have broken during the process, you can try resetting your Unity and/or Compiz configuration:

- [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)
- [How can I reset compiz to the default settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36163/how-can-i-reset-compiz-to-the-default-settings)