# Why do I get the error message "Failed to load session Ubuntu-2D"?

Tags: 11.10, unity, unity-2d

My Ubuntu 11.10 installation worked real good for two weeks. After the first few ubuntu updates (I am not sure if this is the cause) I am not able to use Unity! When I login to Ubuntu 2D, I get the following error:

> Failed to load session "Ubuntu-2d"

The only option in this popup is a logout button. Hence, I am not able to use unity. When I try to login to unity, at times it work.. but launcher and panel does not start. I have to press Ctrl+Alt+T to get a terminal and start the launcher manually!

How do I solve these problems? I did reach but I am not able to see others facing this issue. I also do not know the location of logs, Please let me know where to look for and I will update this question with more information.

Thanks for the help.

**ps:** Currently I use the Gnome-shell with no problem. I am also able to login to gnome classic.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a Ubuntu bug.

See bug reports:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-2d/+bug/934365

Similar questions:

- [What could cause "normal" Ubuntu not to work but Ubuntu-2d to work? 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72978/what-could-cause-normal-ubuntu-not-to-work-but-ubuntu-2d-to-work-11-10)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/142184/12-04-failed-to-load-session-gnome-classic