# How to increase the limit of unity launcher's sensibility

Tags: launcher, configuration, hud

When I change the sensibility of the launcher in the "Change Desktop Background/Behaviour", for the auto-hide mode, it doesn't really change.  I can't appreciate the change. As a consequence it is hard to bring it up and annoying.
Is it like that in all PCs or is it in the Apple Computers?

Comment: Possible duplicate? - http://askubuntu.com/questions/127704/the-auto-hide-function-of-launcher-does-not-work-well

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the Unity launcher delay?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37083/how-can-i-change-the-unity-launcher-delay)

Answer (score 1):

Install [CompizConfig Settings Manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/compizconfig-settings-manager)[image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]. Open it and edit `Ubuntu Unity Plugin`: Set `Launcher Reveal Pressure` to 1 (instead of 20 - default).

Be careful with changing settings in CCSM, though!

Comment: What do you mean by be careful with changing?

Comment: It sometimes happend to me that some things didn't work as they should after I changed some settings in CCSM. You can reset all these settings by [doing what is described here](http://askubuntu.com/a/71931/46531).