# How to show all windows of one application again when I click its icon in the launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, workspace-switcher

It is the original function for 12.04, but it does not work in my computer, maybe as I use the compiz config settings manager, so there are some conflicts.
What can I do to fix it? There are too many parameters in the CCSM, wish you help.

[What I mean:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105400/how-to-disable-the-grouping-of-windows-on-the-launcher)
[image]

Comment: Try not to use CCSM if you can avoid it. Also, see if you get what you want by pressing Super + W. The Super key is usually the Windows key on most keyboards.

Comment: yes, I can achieve it by super+w, but it will show all the applications, but I want to only show  all of the windows in one application. Beside, How to avoid using CCSM? Thank you~

Comment: Take a look at my answer, I updated it according to your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to have a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71926/resetting-ccsm-settings) to learn how to reset Compiz' settings.

If you don't want to mess up your Compiz settings in future, use **MyUnity** instead of CompizConfig Settings Manager. There are less options, but it is safe to use them.

[image: Install via the software center]

Answer (score 2):

I found that the Unity function to show all windows for an App fails if Chrome is currently showing any notifications (e.g. calendar notifications in the bottom-right of the screen). If I delete all my notifications then the function works correctly.

Hopefully Unity will fix this bug in due course, but in the mean time, closing notifications seems to do the trick at least for me.