# Reset all ubuntu 11.10 compiz settings to default

Tags: 11.10, settings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reset compiz to the default settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36163/how-can-i-reset-compiz-to-the-default-settings)

Is there a way to reset all settings of compiz in Ubuntu 11.10 to their defaults? I totally messed up and it is causing a lot of problems on my computer, so please suggest a solution.

Comment: It would be better if you could give us some hint as to what you were doing, as reinstalling resets your settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a new user. Please log in with the new user and copy your old data in the directories of the new user.

Remember when creating the new user, that he must have administrative rights.

In order to obtain the administrative rights that you can copy the files from the old user, you start nautilus with sudo

$ `sudo nautilus`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest backing up all your stuff using a live CD (if you cannot turn on your computer) and reinstall Ubuntu.  I recommend installing 12.04.

There really isn't an efficient way to reset Ubuntu since it doesn't come with your computer by default.(after hours of Googling)

Answer (score 0):

What settings are you looking to 'reset'?  If you have properly partitioned your OS from your home directory, then a quick format of the root partition  followed by a reinstall of the OS would quickly reset all 11.10 System settings to default.

Comment: sorry..I am having a lot of problems with Ubuntu 11.10.some times the mouse just freezes and some times everything like the launcher vanishes! now all icons of folders and file vanished.so please suggest a solution..

Answer (score 0):

Edit: actually, dont try ccsm. I just did and it wasnt pretty. It doesnt reset to Unity-compiz defaults but disable EVERYTHING, so you end up without unity, window decoration, and pretty much anything.. Sorry.