# Is there a way to __DISABLE__ Compiz' Expo plugin's EXPO Animations (ZOOM, etc)?

Tags: 12.04, compiz, workspaces, ccsm

Perhaps **gconf-editor** or **dconf-editor** could help do the trick? However, rumors about **CCSM**'s wanton stability would prevent me from becoming too experimental about this...

Who's **Expo**'s maintainer? Who could just *"add that line of code" ?*

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just install `compizconfig-settings-manager` and run `ccsm`.

On the `Expo` panel, open the `Behavior` tab, and lower the `Zoom time` to its lowest value. It won't completely remove the animation, but will make it almost unnoticeable.

Yes, you can break things by using `ccsm`, but you can always [reset all the compiz options back to their default values if you mess something up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36163/how-can-i-reset-compiz-to-the-default-settings).

Comment: Already have/had "**immediate moves**" enabled, does **not** make a bit of a difference (on my system, at least). Further, Compiz has given me some practice over the past of using tty and ctrl alt f1 etc - but I prefer to do without _any_ crashes (graphical or otherwise).

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my answer. It seems there is no possible configuration value to completely remove this animation, but you can make it almost unnoticeable.

Comment: Perhaps I need to rephrase my original question... I had already minimized the **zoom time** of "**0.1000**", which, I agree, - assuming units are seconds - should be fast (in theory). In practice, however, running on a IBM Thinkpad X41 (albeit with SSD etc) with ~ 500 Firefox tabs (not all of them currently loaded) and a handful of other medium-weight applications going, frequent switching (of workspaces and applications), those nominal "0.1000" rarely deliver on time.