# Compiz high CPU

Tags: unity, graphics, compiz, intel-graphics, cpu-load

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 (my first Linux) alongside Windows 7. When I booted for the first time and ever since Compiz is eating up my CPU. When idle and doing nothing window management related, Compiz keeps at 1-3%. But when opening programs or moving them, everything slows down and Compiz eats up my CPU(sometimes up to 200%)

I collected some info (but I'm new to Linux, so I can't make anything of it):
here are some files (hope it works :) ):

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByqBt-gs2jaRQzliS3dGUFI5T28&usp=sharing

  -details: details about my system
  -lspci: output of `lspci`
  -syslog: copy of my syslog
  -compiz restart crash & compiz crash: I restarted Compiz with `compiz --replace ccp`, it crashed and this is the output in the terminal
  -Xorg.0.log: copy of file with same name; Xorg also takes some CPU power: usually 1-5%



Is it possible Compiz is running on my CPU, rather than my GPU?

And, as it says 'Unity not supported by your hardware' and 'using software rendering', is it my GPU or drivers not working? (I installed none, btw)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

To get latest drivers for the graphic card go to software center, edit(in the menu bar), software sources, additional drivers.
You should find proprietary drivers for your GPU here.

Compiz usually doesn't use much cpu even if it's running on CPU. 
This may be caused by many programs opening at once, or there is some conflict between plugins.
Restoring compiz to default setting should solve that.
See here how to restore Compiz to default [look here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36163/how-can-i-reset-compiz-to-the-default-settings)