# Set scaling back to default

Tags: unity

I accidentally set the scaling settings at 4, and couldn't reset them.
Is there any way to reset these settings back to default?
I'm running a Microsoft Surface Pro (10.6", 1920x1080), and I cannot see the slider.
I have tried all the ways people posted and this hasn't worked.
Using Pre-Ubuntu 14.04 Final Beta (Beta 1).
So i am editing this post and hopes a moderator will unlock it because none of the answers work for me.

Comment: can you not slide the scaling back to 1. or can't you see the slider after it got scaled? be specific

Comment: I cannot see the slider at all. I'm running on a 1920x1080, 10.6" display

Comment: @Jobin that answer doesn't work for me, it crashes unity.

Comment: @wolfy1339 Please try the answers in the following Q&As to reset your Unity and GNOME configuration: [1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration), [2](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults). This Q&A might be of help as well: http://askubuntu.com/questions/36163/how-can-i-reset-compiz-to-the-default-settings.

Comment: please unlock this thread, as none of these solutions work for me. And it is no longer a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

If you can couple a keyboard to it, you should realize that pressing the alt key and then dragging the window will actually relocate the the window even beyond the borders of the screen. Which means that you should be able to push the "displays" window upwards so that the slider comes on the screen. Then you can adjust it back to normal. Kudos to using Ubuntu on MS-surface pro.

Comment: this crashes unity. How do i purge and reinstall unity